# How to partially populate transaction view with master data after supplying identifier in view asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Asp.Net.Core 2.2; EF Core, VS 2017

I am trying to enter a transaction row that uses customer data from a master table. That is, I enter a customer identifier then either through onblur(Ajax) or a separate submit, I get name and address to populate the page.

I have tried using onblur to retrieve the data using Ajax but date and browser issues when trying to display the returned data make that approach problematic.

Now I have added a 'Validate Customer' button to submit view to controller, populate that view with the retrieved data then return the view. But this means 'dual purposing' the 'POST' action handler for the view by examining a name field for blanks ( true means I must get the name from a master table, populate those fields in the returned data, leaving transaction data in that view blank).

When the Action Handler exits, model validation errors are thrown and the retrieved data is not displayed.

This is the button def (some language elements removed so it displays):

```
<button formmethod="post" 
        asp-controller="Registrations"
        asp-action="CreateStdInfo" 
        disableValidation="true"  
        type="submit">
       Check Customer 
</button>
```

Any suggestions for entering an Identifier for a transaction then retrieving related Master Data for display while collecting the rest of the data from the user would be helpful.
Also, guidance on suppressing validations temporarily or conditionally could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change the design of the app to use a single field view to collect the Primary key, retrieve the data in the controller and return the data.

Javascript was a poor choice for this task.